# How to deal with Registry permissions for non admin users for Native messaging

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

Please help me on Native messaging Registry permissions:

How to deal with Registry permissions for non admin users for Native messaging.

Thanks,

Pravin

Comment: You don't need administrative permissions to write in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts`.

Comment: ok, thanks for your prompt response.